# Archivos duplicados al subirlos en ASP.NET MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

Tengo el siguiente código el cual utilizo para dar de alta imágenes y pdf's, el problema es que hasta el momento cuando doy de alta por ejemplo dos imágenes diferentes me guarda 1 pero 2 veces. Y en el caso del PDF lo que quiero es que me guarde sólo uno para las imágenes que suba. Al darlos de alta guardo la URL tanto de las imágenes como de pdf.

El `<input>` que uso para las imágenes es un `multiple`.

```
public ActionResult Insertar_Datos(string Pais, string fecAct, string fecVen, string tituloLanzamiento, string nombreBanner, HttpPostedFileBase urlImg, HttpPostedFileBase urlPdf)
        {
            for(int i = 0; i<Request.Files.Count; i++)
            {
                HttpPostedFileBase file = Request.Files[i];
                if (file.ContentLength > 0) 
                { 
                    string ruta = Request.MapPath("Imagenes_Landing/");
                    Random r = new Random();
                    int numero = r.Next(5, 10000000);
                    nombreBanner = nombreBanner.Replace(" ", "_");
                    if (Directory.Exists(ruta) == false)
                    Directory.CreateDirectory(ruta);
                    string archivo = Path.GetFileName(urlImg.FileName);
                    string extension = Path.GetExtension(archivo);
                    archivo = archivo.Substring(archivo.LastIndexOf(".") + 1).ToLower();
                    archivo = "Imagen_" + numero + '_' + Pais + extension;
                    urlImg.SaveAs(ruta + archivo);
                    string urlImgen = "/Home/Imagenes_Landing/" + archivo;
                    nombreBanner = nombreBanner.Replace("_", " ");

                    ///////////// GUARDADO DE PDFs
                    string rutaPDF = Request.MapPath("PDFs_Landing/");
                    Random ra = new Random();
                    int numeroP = r.Next(5, 10000000);
                    tituloLanzamiento = tituloLanzamiento.Replace(" ", "_");
                    if (Directory.Exists(rutaPDF) == false)
                        Directory.CreateDirectory(rutaPDF);
                    string documento = Path.GetFileName(urlPdf.FileName);
                    string extensionP = Path.GetExtension(documento);
                    documento = documento.Substring(documento.LastIndexOf(".") + 1).ToLower();
                    documento = "Documento_" + numeroP + '_' + Pais + extensionP;
                    string urlPDF = "/Home/PDFs_Landing/" + documento;
                    urlPdf.SaveAs(rutaPDF + documento);
                    nombreBanner = nombreBanner.Replace("_", " ");


                ViewBag.Message = ManejoDatos.AgregarRegistro_LandingPage("Amairani Fernanda Rodriguez", Pais, fecAct, fecVen, tituloLanzamiento, nombreBanner, urlImgen, urlPDF );
                }

            }
                    return RedirectToAction("NuevosLanzamientos", "Home");
        }
```

Lo que busco es que si subo 4 imágenes todas sean diferentes no la misma y con el pdf que no me lo duplique sino que sea 1 pdf por las 4 imágenes

Si alguien me pudiera ayudar, estaría muy agradecida :D

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Por si alguna vez alguien llega a necesitarlo, se resolvió de la siguiente manera:

En el controlador se creo un método para dar de alta el PDF y se mando llamar en mi metodo donde se dan de alta las imagenes.

```
[HttpPost]
        public string InsertarPDF(HttpPostedFileBase urlPdf, string tituloLanzamiento, string Pais)
        {
            string rutaPDF = Request.MapPath("PDFs_Landing/");
            Random ra = new Random();
            int numeroP = ra.Next(5, 10000000);
            tituloLanzamiento = tituloLanzamiento.Replace(" ", "_");
            if (Directory.Exists(rutaPDF) == false)
                Directory.CreateDirectory(rutaPDF);
            string documento = Path.GetFileName(urlPdf.FileName);
            string extensionP = Path.GetExtension(documento);
            documento = documento.Substring(documento.LastIndexOf(".") + 1).ToLower();
            documento = "Documento_" + numeroP + '_' + Pais + extensionP;
            string urlPDF = "/Home/PDFs_Landing/" + documento;
            urlPdf.SaveAs(rutaPDF + documento);


            //nombreBanner = nombreBanner.Replace("_", " ");
            return urlPDF;

        }
        public ActionResult Insertar_Datos(string Pais, string fecAct, string fecVen, string tituloLanzamiento,
             IEnumerable<HttpPostedFileBase> urlImg, HttpPostedFileBase urlPdf)
        {
            string urlPDF = InsertarPDF(urlPdf, tituloLanzamiento, Pais);
            foreach(HttpPostedFileBase file in urlImg)
            {

                    string ruta = Request.MapPath("Imagenes_Landing/");
                    Random r = new Random();
                    int numero = r.Next(5, 10000000);
                    //nombreBanner = nombreBanner.Replace(" ", "_");
                    if (Directory.Exists(ruta) == false)
                    Directory.CreateDirectory(ruta);
                    string archivo = Path.GetFileName(file.FileName);
                    string extension = Path.GetExtension(archivo);
                    archivo = archivo.Substring(archivo.LastIndexOf(".") + 1).ToLower();
                    archivo = "Imagen_" + numero + '_' + Pais + extension;
                    file.SaveAs(ruta + archivo);
                    string urlImgen = "/Home/Imagenes_Landing/" + archivo;

                    ViewBag.Message = ManejoDatos.AgregarRegistro_LandingPage("Amairani Fernanda Rodriguez", Pais, fecAct, fecVen, tituloLanzamiento,
                                    urlImgen, urlPDF);
                }


                    return RedirectToAction("NuevosLanzamientos", "Home");
        }
```

En el método que se llama Insertar_Datos se creo una lista para las imágenes, y recorriendolo con el foreach.

Answer (score 1):

si en el action defines dos parametros `HttpPostedFileBase urlImg, HttpPostedFileBase urlPdf`, no deberias usar el Request.Files ya que si en el post si defines:

```
<input type="file" name="urlImg" />
<input type="file" name="urlPdf" />
```

podrias tomar los archivos directo en los parametros del action, veras que el `name` coincide con los nombre del parametro del action, de esta forma tendras los dos files separados sin tener que iterar en un loop.

Ademas realizas el save dos veces de la misma variable, si bien haces el loop con el for de los `Request.Files` al final terminas usando `urlPdf` en la linea

```
urlPdf.SaveAs(rutaPDF + documento);
```

en donde esta variable es el pdf que subes al realizar el submit, deberias hacer el save utilizando `file`

```
file.SaveAs(rutaPDF + documento);
```

que es la variable que defines en el `for`

Comment: entonces esto no es necesario for(int i = 0; i<Request.Files.Count; i++)
            {
                HttpPostedFileBase file = Request.Files[i]; }?

Comment: si usas los parametros del action no

Comment: Pero si quito el for me guarda sólo una, y si lo pongo pues me guarda varias pero todas son la misma imagen

Comment: tienes que hacer el save de urlImg y urlPdf ya que alli recibiras los archivos

Comment: la verdad es que no te logro entender muy bien

Comment: apunto a que aplique el model binding, si defines los <input type=file> con el name coincidente con los parametros del action estos archivo se inyectan directo alli, no necesitas usar el Request.Files, porque ya tienes los archivos en el action, es mas uno de estos ya lo estas usando cuando haces el urlPdf.SaveAs() solo te falta hacer el urlImg.SaveAs()

Comment: [Continuemos el debate en el chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/60450/discussion-between-amairani-fernanda-and-leandro-tuttini).